# Texture Paint trouble

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

When I open an object in Texture Paint mode and set the view to Solid the colors show up as inverted in the 3D view. The colors show correctly in Render or Material view. This is something new as I was Texture Painting this file yesterday and was able to see the right colors with the view set to Solid.
[image]
And if that wasn't bad enough now a new complication has crept up.  When I switch to Texture Paint the color portion of the UV Map is switching to that of another object. The outlines however stay the same, just resized to fit over the other UV map. In the 3D view this is only visible with Solid View set.
[image]
[image]

[PACKED BLEND FILE](https://we.tl/t-fVksppYEwo)

Any help sorting this out will be appreciated.

Comment: there is no image in your blend file because they are all in your harddrive. To make the things easier, could you please compile them into your blend file? Go in the File menu > External Data > Pack All Into, then share again.

Comment: The original Blend file has been replaced by a packed version.

Answer (score 2):

In the *Tools* panel > *Slots* tab, you need to disable the *Mask* option, and come back to the *Canvas Image* you're using in your material (called *AliBody-Color Diffuse Color*)

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  That solves the problem with the inverted colors.

Comment: However when going into Texture Paint the color file in the UV/Image Editor reverts to the one from the last object opened and is shown overlaid by the current grid.  It is then is overlaid onto the current object in the 3D View until the file in the UV/Image Editor is manually changed.  Leaving Texture Paint and then returning to it repeats the error.

Comment: The correct color file is never shown in Texture Paint with Solid view.